# Constructing Binary Tree Diagram

Tags: c#, binary-tree

This is a [Binary Tree](http://www.dijksterhuis.org/implementing-a-generic-binary-tree-in-c/) diagram. I am having trouble understanding how the diagram was created. You have 5 at the top, but how do you decide what numbers come next and what order? Could someone walk me through this step-by-step?

Comment: Do you want to know how the nodes are added to a binary tree or how C# specifically implements binary trees?

Comment: The inputs are {5, 2, 1, 3, 4...}.  5 is first.  2 is next: since it's less than 5, it goes to the left.  1 is next: since it's less then 5, and less than 2, it, too, goes to the left.  Then 3: it's less than 5 (left), but more than 2.  So it goes to the *right* of 2.  And so on.  Q: Make sense?

Comment: @paulsm4- OMG THANK YOU!!!!!! That makes so much sense now. However, I don't understand how 6 got to the right hand of 4?

Comment: @paulsm4 - Correct me if I am wrong but is it because its greater than 2,3,4?

Comment: @GrantVS - I wanted to know how C# added the nodes to the binary tree, so for example 5 came first and then 2, why on the left said, then 1 why does it go on the left side. Basically how to create that diagram

Comment: @SylviaRosemond: The diagram is wrong. Assuming the naïve algorithm, the 6 should be 5's right-side child, with 10 and 7 under it.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos - You saved me, I was thinking the same thing. Thought I was going crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse,

Well you said this is Binary Tree. So this is the algorithm:
When inserting new numbers, if the number is smaller, it goes left
if it is bigger, it goes right. You should check this applet for 
generating Binary Trees to understand how it works

[link to applet](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~goodrich/dsa/trees/btree.html)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are specifically confused about the diagram at that link. The diagram appears to have an error.

As others have said, there are multiple valid arrangements, but the requirement for a sorted binary tree is that the left subtree of each node contains only smaller elements, and the right subtree contains only larger elements.

In the diagram at the link provided in your question this is violated since 6 > 5. The element 6 belongs in the right subtree of 5, it appears to be a simple mistake by the author.

Comment: BTW, if you exchange 5 and 6 on both left column and inside the tree, sample will be correct )

Answer (score 0):

The specific arrangement of numbers isn't canonical (i.e., other valid arrangements exist). The only requirement is that the left subtree of each node contains only smaller nodes, and the right subtree contains only larger nodes.

The way you come about a particular arrangement depends on the algorithm(s) used to populate it and the order in which the values are inserted. This is partly explained in the article in the "Balancing the tree" section. As you insert, you need to keep the tree balanced. How often you rebalance, and how you rebalance is the subject of millions of pages of textbooks, research papers and lines of code.

In short, the answer to your question is, "It depends."

For the naïve implementation, which doesn't necessarily produce balanced trees, each insertion simply walks the tree, going left if the number is smaller than the currently visited node, or right if it's larger (ignoring equal values, which you'd need to either ensure don't happen or decide on a policy for handling them). When you reach a dead end (i.e., a null left- or right-pointer), plonk a new node there with the inserted value.

> Sidebar: It's worth noting that the naïve algorithm can, on rare occasions, be just what you need, thanks to its simplicity. You can avoid unbalanced trees simply by randomly shuffling the input data before inserting. In most cases, however, you're better off not even using a binary tree. Hash tables are almost always preferable.